# Point moving in circular path instead of straight line- OPENGL

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I am trying to make a point follow the cursor in 2d. The point should be directly under the cursor at all times. I have tried using ray casting but the point is moving in circular path instead of 2d straight line.

I think maybe I need to constraint the point movement by a plane but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
   protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseMoveEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseState mstate = Mouse.GetCursorState();
            mousePos1 = this.PointToClient(new Point(mstate.X, mstate.Y));
        }



    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {

            Matrix4 projectionM = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(-1.05f, 1.05f, -1.25f, 1.25f, 
            -100f, 100.0f);
            Matrix4 viewM = Matrix4.Identity ;
            Vector3 cursorPos = raycasting(mousePos1.x, mousePos1.y, projectionM, viewM);
            float[] cursors = new float[] { cursorPos.X, cursorPos.Y,cursorPos.Z};
            //binding buffer arrays//
            shader4.Use();
            GL.UniformMatrix4(0, false, ref viewM);
            GL.UniformMatrix4(1, false, ref projectionM);
            shader4.SetFloat("color", new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1));
            GL.BindVertexArray(_vao);
            GL.PointSize(5);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Points, 0, 1);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
            shader4.Unbind();
           }

 private Vector3 raycasting(float X, float Y, Matrix4 proj, Matrix4 vi)
        {
                float x = (2.0f * X) /(float) this.Width - 1.0f;
                float y = 1.0f;
                float z = 1.0f;

                Vector3 normalized_device_coordinates_ray = new Vector3(x, y, z);

                // Homogeneous Clip Coordinates
                Vector4 homogeneous_clip_coordinates_ray = new Vector4(normalized_device_coordinates_ray.X, normalized_device_coordinates_ray.Y, -1.0f, 1.0f);

                // 4D Eye (Camera) Coordinates
                Vector4 camera_ray = Matrix4.Invert(proj) * homogeneous_clip_coordinates_ray;
                camera_ray = new Vector4(camera_ray.X, camera_ray.Y, -1.0f, 0.0f);

                // 4D World Coordinates
                Vector3 world_coordinates_ray = (Matrix4.Invert(vi) * camera_ray).Xyz;
                world_coordinates_ray.Normalize();

            return world_coordinates_ray;
        }
```

There are two main issue with this:

1. As I said the point moves in circular or radial movement instead of straight line like the cursor
2. The point isn't directly under the cursor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalized device coordinates are in range [-1, 1]. Get the NDC coordinates form the window coordinates as follows:

```
float x = 2.0f * X / (float)this.Width - 1.0f;
float y = 1.0f - 2.0f * Y / (float)this.Height;
```

In general you have to divide by the `xyz` components by the w component after the transformation by the inverse projection matrix ([Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide)). You can skip that, because you use a orthographic projection and the w component is 1.

But since you use orthographic projection, you do not compute a ray, you compute a point. Thus the normalization of `world_coordinates_ray` is wrong.

```
Vector3 world_coordinates_ray = (Matrix4.Invert(vi) * camera_ray).Xyz;
// world_coordinates_ray.Normalize(); <--- DELETE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! Was stuck for a long time.This solved the movement issue but there is still a bit of offset that seems to increase as the the mouse goes to the screen sides/edges but the offset goes away when the cursor is around the origin. What is the reason behind it?How can I fix it?